# Library not found only when application is executed from PBS file.

Tags: library, pbs, torque

I have a compiled file a.out that runs fine when executed directly from my terminal. However, trying to execute that file from my PBS file yields a missing library `libmkl_intel_lp64.so`. I have already tried

- exporting the path of the library to LD_LIBARY_PATH
- using `source a.out intel64` to link the executable in my PBS file

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How did you compile a.out? I think for MKL you need a linking option (-L).

Comment: If it runs correctly from OP's terminal doesn't he have the binary linked properly?